# Evaluate the definite integral using idea of periodic functions

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Evaluate

$\int_{\frac{25\pi}{4}}^{\frac{53\pi}{4}}\frac{1}{\left(1+2^{\sin x}\right) \left(1+2^{\cos x}\right)}dx$

My Attempt:

I tried using the property that $\int_{a}^{b}f\left(a+b-x\right)dx=\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$ and properties of periodic functions but ended up with a mess.
The answer is $\frac{7\pi}{4}$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/463881/evaluate-int-25-pi-453-pi-4-frac112-sin-x12-cos-xdx?rq=1, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/914652/trigonometric-integral-int-25-pi-453-pi-4-frac112-sin-x12?rq=1, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1785309/find-int-pi-465-pi-4-fracdx12-cos-x12-sin-x/1785364#1785364